# react router 2, return 404 status

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react router v 2.8.1 and am trying to set up my 404 page for my SPA. I am having trouble getting it to actually send back a 404. I am trying to do this so google will not index that page for me.

So far, I have tried setting a catch all route to get any unknown routes inside my Router -

```
 <Router>
    ...

    <Route
        path='*'
        status={404}
        getComponent={(location, cb) => {
          require.ensure([], require => {
            const component = require('./components/404/component.jsx').default;

            cb(null, component);
          });
        }}/>
   </Router>
```

This works fine for showing the content. Via googling, I found some people using the `status={404}`, however I am not seeing it doing anything for me. Is there a way to force a 404 status back from react router (2.8.1)? Thanks!

Comment: You should upgrade to v4, and set up both client and server routers https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering/404-401-or-any-other-status

Comment: @AdamAzad I am fairly limited as there is no server rendering and I am stuck with this version.

Comment: you can't trigger a 404 from client side - that needs to come from the server

Answer (score 2):

Since I am not using server rendering/routing , it is not really possible to get a 404 response, atleast from what I can find right now. So my solution is to just add a noIndex meta tag, to prevent google from indexing any 404 page it might come across. I use Helmet js, so in my 404 Component I just do:

```
<Helmet
    title={'Not Found'}
    meta={[
      {name: 'ROBOTS', content: 'NOINDEX'}
    ]}
  />
```

Which just translates to:

```
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX">
```

This works for me for now, I will leave it here incase anyone runs across the same issue. Unless someone solves this, in which case please submit an answer.

Comment: Be careful of static resource paths. The browser will still parse the response as `text/css` `javascript/application` but the content is HTML, and this will trigger an error in console. Happy coding